# Google Play Game Services not signing it

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

my app is on the store and I've tested a lot before uploading and its working fine, today while I was debugging different stuff, suddenly the Google Play Game Services stopped signing in, I've tried different devices and I haven't been able to log in, after installing from the store.

Sorry I don't have any code to share cause am sure it's not my code and the bugs I was trying with are not related, Oh and one more thing, my achievments button is also acting wierd, it's not responding. It doesn't start the activity that's requested ..

Comment: Tried on a different device, a different Google account?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing works :S

Comment: Then it's most likely something wrong with your code. Google Play Game Services works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Terribly sorry on this one guys, I figured it out by mistake lol, I had the activity launch mode as single instance

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

in the manifest, removed it and all is good now. Sorry :)